# Parse all the XML Tags including nested tags into Single row in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-stage

I want all the tags in the below XML to be parsed into single row of a snowflake table. I have the XML data stored in the variant column in the table. Is this possible ?
I am not able to parse the PrivateData and Agent tags into the same row. I need it all the tag values in single row of the destination table.

I would need the table structure as below

Table 1

| AccNo | VALIDITY | SID | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 045566057 | 647096 | 209415163 | Abbas,Bilal | http://localhost/ |

Table 2

| SID | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 209415163 | CD7 | SVC_CFS_TRNF_CUST_GUID |
| 209415163 | CD11 | 00FA08000637E861F35118 |

I want all the key value in that Dictionary array.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <CTest
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CRI>
        <StartTime>2022-01-28T02:14:28.8000000+0000</StartTime>
        <AccNo>0455660547</AccNo>
        <VALIDITY>647096</VALIDITY>
        <Direction>1</Direction>
        <PrivateData>
            <PrivateData>
                <DictionaryEntry>
                    <Key>CD7</Key>
                    <Value>SVC_CFS_TRNF_CUST_GUID</Value>
                </DictionaryEntry>
                <DictionaryEntry>
                    <Key>CD11</Key>
                    <Value>00FA08000637E861F35118</Value>
                </DictionaryEntry>
                <DictionaryEntry>
                    <Key>CD12</Key>
                    <Value>00FA08000637E861F35118</Value>
                </DictionaryEntry>
                <DictionaryEntry>
                    <Key>CD15</Key>
                    <Value>131336</Value>
                </DictionaryEntry>
                <DictionaryEntry>
                    <Key>CD17</Key>
                    <Value>QEP_CFS_TRNF_CGUIDE_CUST_GUID</Value>
                </DictionaryEntry>
                <DictionaryEntry>
                    <Key>CD21</Key>
                    <Value>WA</Value>
                </DictionaryEntry>
            </PrivateData>
        </PrivateData>
        <Channel>5455</Channel>
        <Unit>1000</Unit>
        <SID>209415163</SID>
        <DBS_ID>797</DBS_ID>
        <ScreenUnit>0</ScreenUnit>
        <LocalStartTime>2022-01-28T13:14:28.8000000+1100</LocalStartTime>
        <LocalEndTime>2022-01-28T13:21:45.8000000+1100</LocalEndTime>
        <ContactID>9146727573060010008</ContactID>
        <SwitchCallID>0087032eb393b083</SwitchCallID>
        <DataSourceName>GCC SIPREC NWT ChildDS1</DataSourceName>
        <IsException>1</IsException>
        <ExceptionReason>1</ExceptionReason>
    </CRI>
    <Agent>
        <GroupsList>
            <int name="Transcribe (1) Colonial First State">0</int>
        </GroupsList>
        <Name>Abbas,Bilal</Name>
        <Organization>Test</Organization>
    </Agent>
    <File>
        <Location>http://localhost/</Location>
        <RawLocation>MM</RawLocation>
        <RawLocationType>File</RawLocationType>
    </File>
    <Instances>
        <CInstance>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Name>CI-Test</Name>
        </CInstance>
    </Instances>
    <XmlVersion>10.0.0.0</XmlVersion> </CTest>
```

Update - I am able to part the table 1 properly. Now in the table 1 I would need to add the DictionaryEntry object which has Key CD7 and its value and CD11 and its value in the same table with CD7 and CD11 ad column name with respective value in the rows.. is this possible?

Comment: Hi - as you have repeating elements how are you expecting this to work? Given your XML document, what columns do you want to create?

Comment: From the CRI Tag , I would need  AccNo, Validity, SID  and Key , Value  from Dictionary tag , then  Name , organization , GroupList name from Agent Tags , and then Location and Raw Location from File Tag.  If we need to do it in different tables, how to set  SID as reference key for all the tables?

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the target table(s) you want to create and what you want to populate them with - based on the data in your example XML document. In order for someone to help you, you need to show what you want to achieve and any constraints on the solution - such as the information you added in your comment about including a SID